Azure DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/project_name) looping logins
Trying to log in to Azure DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/project_name) but am getting looping logins regardless of which project I try.
I can login to https://aex.dev.azure.com/ to see the list of my projects, but cannot access any of them. I can create a new one via here, but cannot access it due to looping logins.
Tried multiple browsers, issue remains the same.

Did you ever successfully log in these Azure DevOps organizations? When was the last time you successfully logged in to the Azure DevOps organizations?

This seems is related to a known sign-in issue that has been reported by multiple people recently.
Below are some tickets reported the similar issues on Developer Community:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cant-login-to-devazurecomorg---Loop/10660522
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-login-into-Azure-DevOps:-Being-re/10658723
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Continuous-Authentication-Loop-and-Error/10657188

You can try to follow these tickets on Developer Community and add you comments on them.
If required, you can open a new ticket on Developer Community to reported the issue, and post a private comment on the ticket to provide the actual names of your Azure DevOps organizations (https://dev.azure.com/organization_name) and the network trace logs related to the issue. Only Microsoft support engineers can see your private comments that might contain your Privacy or Sensitive Information.
